# How to map a C-struct with bitfields in JNR?

Tags: java, struct, jnr

I have the following [struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that i want to map using [JNR-FFI](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi). Note that this struct contains bitfields. Unfortunatly there is no JavaDoc or any other kind of doc available.

```
typedef struct _DCB {
  DWORD DCBlength;
  DWORD BaudRate;
  DWORD fBinary  :1;
  DWORD fParity  :1;
  DWORD fOutxCtsFlow  :1;
  DWORD fOutxDsrFlow  :1;
  DWORD fDtrControl  :2;
  DWORD fDsrSensitivity  :1;
  DWORD fTXContinueOnXoff  :1;
  DWORD fOutX  :1;
  DWORD fInX  :1;
  DWORD fErrorChar  :1;
  DWORD fNull  :1;
  DWORD fRtsControl  :2;
  DWORD fAbortOnError  :1;
  DWORD fDummy2  :17;
  WORD  wReserved;
  WORD  XonLim;
  WORD  XoffLim;
  BYTE  ByteSize;
  BYTE  Parity;
  BYTE  StopBits;
  char  XonChar;
  char  XoffChar;
  char  ErrorChar;
  char  EofChar;
  char  EvtChar;
  WORD  wReserved1;
}
```

Comment: I think that you are unlikely to get any useful info here.  From what I can make out, JEP 191 and JNR are under active development, and the information you want is not available outside of the experts group. You could try asking the principles for the project, but I suspect they will just tell you to wait.